# ¿Por que cuando hago clic sobre mi componente se desborda en el eje X? y ¿Por que si le pongo margen a mi componente también se desborda en el eje X?

Tags: css, reactjs, web-components

Tengo un componente en React js con estilos de tailwind que funciona como acordeón, al yo hacer clic sobre el se me despliega mas información. Lo estoy usando como una especia de tabla para mostrar un nombre de una base de datos. Cuando yo pongo datos manuales el componente funciona de forma normal, sin embargo, cuando traigo los datos de mi base de datos el componente se comporta de forma rara. Si el componente tiene margen se borda en x y al hacer clic sobre el la animación que se muestra al desplegar la información es lenta, cosa que no pasa al poner los datos de forma manual.

Este es el código del componente.

````
```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const DebtorsTable = ({ name }) => {
  const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (showInfo === null) {
      setShowInfo(true);
    } else if (showInfo) {
      setShowInfo(false);
    } else {
      setShowInfo(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="mt-5 bg-[#C0C0C3] bg-opacity-20 border-white/10 border-[1px] shadow-md shadow-black/80 rounded-md">
      <div
        className={`cursor-pointer flex justify-between items-center`}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {name}
        <i
          className={`bi bi-arrow-up-short text-2xl transition-all duration-100
      ${showInfo ? "rotate-180" : ""}`}
        ></i>
      </div>
      <p
        className={`
    ${
      showInfo ? "h-[5rem]" : "h-0"
    } transition-all duration-75 overflow-hidden`}
      >
        algo
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DebtorsTable;
```
````

y este es el código del componente en la vista dahsboard

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { store } from "../context/Context";

import Title from "../titles/Title";
import SignOffButton from "../buttons/SignOffButton";
import AddDebtorButton from "../buttons/AddDebtorButton";
import FilterInput from "../input/FilterInput";
import AddDebtorModal from "../modals/AddDebtorModal";

import DebtorsTable from "../tables/DebtorsTable";

const Dashboard = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getDebtors();
  }, []);

  const { activeModal, getDebtors, debtorsCopy } = useContext(store);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`${activeModal && "blur-sm"} 
        w-[100vw] h-[100vh] realtive  pt-5 pl-4 pr-4  animate__animated animate__fadeIn animate__faster`}
      >
        <div id="title-and-signoff-button" className="mb-5">
          <div className="flex justify-between items-start 450px:relative 450px:justify-center">
            <Title title={"NOTE COBRO"} titleColor={"text-white"} />
            <div className="450px:absolute 450px:right-0">
              <SignOffButton />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="add-and-filter-deptors" className="flex justify-between gap-2">
          <div className="w-full">
            <FilterInput />
          </div>
          <AddDebtorButton />
        </div>

        {
          <>
            {debtorsCopy.map((debtor) => (
              <React.Fragment key={debtor._id}>
                <DebtorsTable name={debtor.name} />
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </>
        }

        {/* <DebtorsTable name={"nombre de algo"} /> */}
      </div>

      <AddDebtorModal />
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

He estado ajustando el ancho del componente a ver si eso es pero no funciona, no entiendo porque sucede esto, y como ya dije solo pasa cuando estoy poniendo los datos de la base de datos.

Al hacer clic sobre el componente el debe desplegar la información que tiene de forma fluida.